# Free dictionary / phrasebook for i18n

Tags: dictionary, internationalization

Is there any free dictionary I can use for i18n?
Free as in open source / creative commons, ideally also for use in a commercial product.

Looking at the KDE i18n projects, they have translated a lot of applications in many languages. Is there a way I can use their dictionaries for a standard Qt (non-KDE) application - and am I allowed to?

Answer (score 0):

You should contact the [KDE localization team](http://i18n.kde.org/contact.php) if you have questions about licensing of their translations.

I don't think that the l10n support of KDE applications will help yoiu directly -- they ship as a catalogue of strings, as appears in a particular context in the original application, and the translated form. There is a long way from that to automatically using the data in the context of another application, and that's also the reason why machine-generated translations have such a low quality. If you cannot speak a language and don't have anyone who could do the work for you, you won't be able to ship a working localized version in that language.